# python datetime module How to compare datetime.time against datetime.now

Tags: python, datetime

I have two set times and I am trying to see if the current time is within those times.
When I attempt to do this I get the error
`TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'str'` 
Below is the code that retrieves this error, How would I properly compare between datetime and time?

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time

start = time(6, 35, 0)
end = time(12, 55, 0)
current = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')

if start <= current <= end:
    print(start, end, current)
```

Comment: Don't make it a string before the comparison?

Comment: Theoretically string comparison would also work, but 1) *all*  variables in comparison then would have to be strings, equally formatted with increasing "granularity" left to right (hours-minutes-seconds), and 2) using datetime.time objects in the comparison is probably less obfuscated and less complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not cast your time to str with `strftime`. You can use `time()` function of `datetime.datetime` to get time of timestamp. The thing you need is

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time

start = time(6, 35, 0)
end = time(12, 55, 0)
current = datetime.now().time()

if start <= current <= end:
    print(start, end, current)
```